# Can't drop .php extension from files in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url

I'm trying to drop to .php extension on my files in the url.  It seems like it should be really easy, but I can't get it to work.

For Example, If I link to a page in my site.

`<a href="/admin_login.php">admin</a>`

the url reads like this

`www.domain.com/admin_login.php`

I want it to read like this

`http://www.domain.com/admin-login`

In my .htaccess file I have this

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

also tried this

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Please don't tell me I have to go through my site and change every link to drop the .php extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please don't tell me I have to go through my site and change every link to drop the .php extension.

You do. Your rewrite rules tell the webserver to send `<anything>` to `<anything>.php`, but that won't magically adjust all the links in your code to use those new alternate URLs.

Comment: ouch. Thanks, but that breaks my links locally, can I add a .htaccess file to my local folder?

Comment: If you're running Apache, sure.